# R Logistic regression and correlation

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interpretation

I'm having trouble understanding the output of this logistic regression in R.

## Data

```
dat <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
    2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1),
  outcome = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  var2 = c(70, 86, 80, 88, 74, 75, 76, 82, 79, 80, 80, 79, 81, 79, 77, 
    75, 77, 75, 70, 65, 67, 86, 87, 70, 81, 66, 76, 62, 62, 73, 65, 
    66, 65, 85, 82, 76, 64, 68, 66, 83, 69, 73, 82, 65, 86, 74, 62, 
    68, 64, 81, 72, 74, 63, 63, 76, 79, 82, 73, 78, 70, 68, 72, 72, 
    60, 73, 73, 74, 86, 77, 81, 63, 79, 74, 76, 83, 85, 61, 83, 73, 
    71, 72, 59, 77, 73, 67, 80, 84, 77, 79, 73, 86, 75, 79, 78, 82, 
    80, 78, 58, 82, 74, 77, 78, 67, 68, 82, 72, 65, 85, 83, 69, 73, 
    78),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

## Regression:

```
fit <- glm(outcome ~  var1 + var2 , 
           data = dat, family = "binomial")
summary(fit)
Call:
glm(formula = outcome ~ var1 + var2, family = "binomial", data = dat)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.61347  -0.00006   0.31030   0.41875   0.74162  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  -47.79642 3650.08385  -0.013    0.990
var1          22.03545 1825.04048   0.012    0.990
var2           0.08264    0.05621   1.470    0.142

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 145.993  on 111  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  45.062  on 109  degrees of freedom
AIC: 51.062

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
```

From the results, the var1 has a very high p value, so my understanding is that in contribute poorly in predicting the 'outcome'.
But when I look at the correlation between the 2, they are highly correlated. And the inverse is true, var2 has a lower p-value but not a good correlation with 'outcome'

Can anyone explain, why ? This is probably trivial, but I can't find the answer.

```
cor(dat)
             var1   outcome      var2
var1    1.0000000 0.8671209 0.1029565
outcome 0.8671209 1.0000000 0.1587125
var2    0.1029565 0.1587125 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, **there's nothing wrong with your model.**  You haven't told us anything about the nature of the data (which appear to have been invented for the sake of demonstration) or the purpose of your model, so I don't see any point in talking about "improving" the model.  It sounds like you would benefit from a better understanding of how correlated predictors affects a regression model.

Let's start with an illustration that may give you a better feeling for what goes on:
Consider a situation in which you're trying to determine the effect of t-shirt color {Red, Blue} and hair color {blonde, dark} on weight {0-100}.

First, you observe a red-shirted blonde person who weighs 50 pounds, and then a blue-shirted dark-haired person who weighs 100 pounds.  Note that in this example, hair color and shirt color appear to be perfectly correlated.

**Based on the data alone**, you would be unable to decide whether a blue shirt has a weight-increasing effect of +50 pounds, or whether dark hair has a weight-increasing effect of +50 pounds.  In terms of the model, the effect of *shirt color* could have no effect (if hair color was the "cause") or it could be fully responsible for the +50 (if hair color had no true effect).

Note that this example is **really oversimplified**, but hopefully the essence is clear -- when two variables are correlated, *it makes it difficult to tell which of the two had the true effect*.  In a model, this translates to an *increase in the variance--or wider confidence intervals* in both variables.

Both of the previous answers pointed out that fitting a model with just *Var1* in it led to the model concluding that *Var1* had a significant effect on the *outcome*.  However, in the full model you have added a second covariate *Var2*, which is highly correlated with *Var1*, and the resulting model has a hard time telling which--if any-- of the two variables has a significant effect on the *outcome*.

One thing that's important to point out is that **larger model (i.e., with *var1* and *var2*) appears to explain the outcome better than a model with just *var1*.**  Note that the AIC of the larger model (51.062) is better than the smaller model fit by @Bernhard (55.045).  This is generally true, as adding correlated predictors to a model does not necessarily result in a "poorer" model.  Rather, it simply means that the parameter estimates will be harder to interpret (i.e. can you really attribute the estimated effect to the associated variable when it is so highly correlated with another variable?)

In short:
You've done nothing wrong; you've simply demonstrated that multicollinearity causes the variance of parameter estimates to increase.  I would caution that your interpretation of a p-value ("that in contribute poorly in predicting the 'outcome'") is problematic and may be one reason why this result seems confusing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just to state the fact. The model is bad in the sense that it overfits and actually none of the predictors are good (significant).

Correlation just reflects the amount of linear association between two objects, it does not necessarily translate into the fact that it will be useful in including the variable in logistic regression when it correlates with the output.

If you plot "var1" vs "outcome" and "var2" vs "outcome", you can see that there is no linear association in var2 vs outcome case and there is some "spurious" correlation in "var1" vs "outcome" case.

Given that you are predicting binary data, your model is using "var1" as the best out of the worst parameters to overfit and give the lowest error.

Consider improving your model.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but may give insight that will help finding an answer.

Looking at your data, `var1` should easily explain `outcome`, mostly on its own:

```
plot(outcome ~ jitter(var1), data=dat)
```

[image]

Yet, `glm` does not come to a "significant" result, as long as there is only `1` and `2` values in `var1`. That somehow leads to enormous standard errors. As soon as you add a little jitter to `var1`, just as I did in the plot above, the standard errors drop drastically and all results are highly significant

```
> summary(glm(outcome ~ jitter(var1), data=dat, family=binomial))

Call:
glm(formula = outcome ~ jitter(var1), family = binomial, data = dat)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.7033  -0.1286   0.2903   0.4610   0.7332  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -11.405      2.988  -3.818 0.000135 ***
jitter(var1)    6.982      1.586   4.402 1.07e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 145.993  on 111  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  51.045  on 110  degrees of freedom
AIC: 55.045

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

Adding jitter increases the residual deviance from `47.29` to `51.0` so the model is not better, just the standard errors are smaller.

I have no conclusive answer as to why the "perfect" `var1` leads to these enormous standard errors but apparantly that is a huge non-obvious part of the problem here.